# cross compiling fails. no rule to make module install

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation

I am trying to cross compile a Linux kernel for my Raspberry Pi. following this [tutorial](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-kernel-compile/).

I am trying to run this command:

```
make modules_install ARCH=arm \
  CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- \
  INSTALL_MOD_PATH=../modules/
```

But always get this error:

No rule to make target 'modules_install'. Stop.

Why? How can I solve it? Should I enable some options in the menuconfig (which I didn't)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to be in the /linux/ folder and then execute the command. Problem solved